# simple jquery loop through JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this simple jquery script to loop through JSON array 
the script is not working at it all and never give output.
im sure that the JSON array is valid but i don't know why Jquery not parsing it .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cost = [{"gold":"100","iron":"80","wood":"120","food":"70"},{"gold":"80","iron":"60","wood":"90","food":"35"}];
    var costarr = $.parseJSON(cost);
    $.each(costarr, function(i, item) {
       alert(item.gold);
    }
});
```

Comment: if you want to play with javascript at least use a browser console to inspect errors thrown...pretty easy to locate syntax errors you have...and it takes all of 3 seconds to do it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You [don't need to parse it](http://jsfiddle.net/fqhYA/), it's already an array. And your `each` lacks a closing `)`

```
$.each(cost, function(i, item) {
  alert(item.gold);
}); //<-- lacking ")"
```

Comment: i tried it before submitting the question but see in Fiddle it still not working http://jsfiddle.net/ShPPC/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

```
$.each(costarr, function(i, item) {
   alert(item.gold);
}
```

is missing the ending ');'

which is why nothing is being alerted in your fiddle.